# How to use Javascript window in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, window, shopify

Im trying to build an embedded Shopify App using this tutorial: https://shopify.dev/tools/app-bridge/getting-started

In the section "Authenticate with OAuth" the author writes following code:

```
// If the current window is the 'parent', change the URL by setting location.href
if (window.top == window.self) {
  window.location.assign(permissionUrl);

  // If the current window is the 'child', change the parent's URL with Shopify App Bridge's Redirect action
} else {
  const app = createApp({
    apiKey: apiKey,
    shopOrigin: shopOrigin
  });

  Redirect.create(app).dispatch(Redirect.Action.REMOTE, permissionUrl);
}
```

The problem is, it is referred to JavaScript window object. But Node JS is used here.

I have tried using jsdom to use JavaScript window object, but it doesnt seem to make it work.

So its 2 questions:

Why does the author use JavaScript window when the code itself is about NodeJS?

And how do I make it work in NodeJS?

Comment: There's nothing in the article that mentions using Node.js

Comment: Why do you say the code is about NodeJS?

Comment: Cause later in the article OAuth is used and I think its NodeJS used here. Also the tutorials use always NodeJS in Shopify

Comment: A bit before that piece of code, a paragraph starts with "*Since embedded applications are loaded inside an iframe [...]*" - embedded iframes are **only** present in a browser environment. Then the text following that discusses how the redirect should happen from the parent by escaping the iframe. Then there is code that checks whether the code is running in an iframe and uses browser-specific calls. So, I don't see how this would be about NodeJS.

Comment: Well, I'm not a Shopify expert but the article is obviously about what happens in the frontend and isn't even using `npm` as it's stating that `npm` is an alternative

Comment: This is from an example where they are talking about front-end code that runs in the browser.  Here's a quote right before that code: ***This means that where the OAuth process would normally begin with redirecting the merchant to the authorization prompt, it should instead return a page containing a script which escapes the frame.***.  So, this is code (designed to escape a frame) within a web page and thus it runs in the browser.

Comment: So, I am using NodeJS with Angular. Does that mean, all the mentioned code in the article belongs into my frontend code?...

Comment: @jfriend00 ?...

Comment: @VLAZ ? ........

Comment: @MohamedOraby ....

Comment: @IonicMan well yes it belongs in your frontend code but I guess you should research how to use it with angular because you're probably gonna use the npm package because I guess using `<script></script>` in angular is a bad idea (or at least it is a bad idea in React)

Comment: @MohamedOraby alright thank you. The script is only an alternative, the tutorial shows 2 different ways.

Comment: The Shopify App Bridge is for the web browser, not for Node.js. Whatever you're trying to do, revise your approach.